# Karate - unable to perform match operation - actual value not string

Tags: karate

```
Scenario Outline: Verify retreiving endpoint for particular system
  Given path 'kites/<id>'
  When method get
  Then status 200
  And match response contains "<orgid>"

  Examples:
    | kites                    | orgid                    |
    | 56338e32e4b0846c32c0732e | 56338e32e4b0846c32c0732e |
```

I am getting the following error:

```
com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: path: $, actual:
{
     "orgId": "56338e32e4b0846c32c0732e",
     "name": "Supplier Management"
}
expected: '56338e32e4b0846c32c0732e', reason: actual value is not a string
```

I tried with `<orgid>` and `"<orgid>"` but i am getting the same error. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are so many things I don't understand in your example. Where did `<id>` come from ? Where is the `kites` column used ?

The most serious problem is you are using `orgid` but the actual JSON has a key `orgId`. Please don't make basic mistakes and try again.

And shouldn't you be trying to do something like this:

```
And match response contains { orgId: "<orgid>" }
```

Edit: Since there are complaints about the above (which I find disappointing), I'm adding another option:

```
And match response.orgId == "<orgid>"
```

Comment: Thanks @Peter. Sorry for the typo mistakes (was trying not to have the business fields).  I was hoping if I could use like: `And match response contains "<orgId>" ` instead of specifying like `{ orgId: "<orgId>"}`

Comment: Why why do you want to do things in a weird way :P Just stick to JSON, is it so strange ?  anyway, see my edit.